# Why does ring give me error in this response?

Tags: clojure, ring

Below is my app -

```
(ns mfaiz.routes
  (:use [net.cgrand.moustache :only [app]]
        [net.cgrand.enlive-html :only [deftemplate content]]
        [ring.util.response :only [response]]))

(deftemplate reg "mfaiz/templates/reg.html" [])

(def my-app (app
             ["hi"] "Hello World!"
             ["reg"] (-> ((-> "reg" symbol resolve)) response constantly) 
             [&] "Nothing was found"))
```

I encounter error with this route -

```
["reg"] (-> ((-> "reg" symbol resolve)) response constantly)
```

If I evaluate the above route directly, it works properly and returns the html file -

```
((-> "reg" symbol resolve))
```

If I also change the route to directly call the template function then also it works -

```
["reg"] (-> (reg) response constantly)
```

Any ideas what is going wrong ?

Comment: Try to use `(-> "mfaiz.routes/reg" symbol resolve)`

Comment: @Ankur thanks, that worked like a charm ! Ankur why do I need to specify the ns, when the symbols are existing in the ns. Also the evaluation is sucessfull without the ns qualification in repl, why so ?

Comment: Also you can post it as an answer, and I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the fact that when it run under ring, the "reg" is not being resolved because the it is not fully qualified. It depends in which namespace the ring server is started. So using fully qualified name will work:

`(-> "mfaiz.routes/reg" symbol resolve)`

Please check `resolve` [documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/resolve). It tries to resolve the symbol in current namespace i.e in `*ns*`